# Screen size problem in android

Tags: android, screen-size

I am creating a native android app targeting all android devices. I have confused about scalability of UI based on screen size. kindly suggest what are the screen sizes I need to consider while developing.

Please reply as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance
M.Sathya.

Answer (score 1):

you need to consider about small screens with density 240x320, medium screens 320x480 and large screens 480x800 or 480x854. check out this [Multiple Screens Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

Android is designed in such a way that everything we make can be run independent of screen size.
Fundamentally you MUST learn about types of layouts and their use.
Also tend to use dp instead of pixels.

For more information go to: [Multiple Screens Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Thanks,